# Microsoft Outlook Mobile Add-in not opening mailto: links

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, mailto, outlook-mobile-addin

When I create a link inside mobile add-in for outlook, it's doing nothing. I was expecting it to open a new email, but it's just doing nothing. Anyone else with the same issue?

i've tried to put `<a hrfe="mailto:zork@nemisj.com">click me</a>` as link, but also tried to put it as a separate page like `<a href="mysite.com/mailto.html">click me</a>` with content of mailto.html to be `<script>document.location = 'mailto:zork@nemisj.com'</script>` with no luck

Answer (score 0):

"mailto" will not launch Mobile Outlook. Currently, there is no supported way of launching outlook mobile through a href.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it, besides a href?

Comment: Currently the feature, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page: https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.